# lua_numbertointeger - why can we assume INT_MIN has an exact representation as a float?

Tags: c, lua

Lua stores numbers internally as either integers or floats. When doing a comparison operation (e.g. less-than) between numbers of the two different types, it needs to convert from one type to the other to make a comparison.

The integer and float types vary depending on configuration / platform, but certain assumptions are made. (I'm only really interested in "normal" 32 or 64 bit two's complement ints and 32 or 64 bit IEEE754 floats).

When the integer type may not have an exact representation in the floating point format, Lua tries to convert the floating point value to an integer.

This is done in a macro `lua_numbertointeger`:

```
/*
@@ lua_numbertointeger converts a float number with an integral value
** to an integer, or returns 0 if float is not within the range of
** a lua_Integer.  (The range comparisons are tricky because of
** rounding. The tests here assume a two-complement representation,
** where MININTEGER always has an exact representation as a float;
** MAXINTEGER may not have one, and therefore its conversion to float
** may have an ill-defined value.)
*/
#define lua_numbertointeger(n,p) \
  ((n) >= (LUA_NUMBER)(LUA_MININTEGER) && \
   (n) < -(LUA_NUMBER)(LUA_MININTEGER) && \
      (*(p) = (LUA_INTEGER)(n), 1))
```

My question is thus:

Assuming that `LUA_NUMBER` is a 32 bit `float`, and `LUA_INTEGER` is a 32 bit `int` **why** can we assume that `LUA_MIN_INTEGER` (i.e. `INT_MIN`) has an exact representation in the floating point type.

(And the same for a 64 bit int and 64 bit floating point... and would it work with 64 bit int and 32 bit float?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 2's complement representation, the minimum value typically has only 1 bit set, as in C's `INT_MIN` which might be `0x80000000`. So it can be exactly represented in a `float` because it has only one significant bit, and can be normalised without loss of precision.

But `INT_MAX` which is say `0x7FFFFFFF` has 31 significant bits, more than the significand of `float` has, and so it cannot be exactly represented by a `float`.

Answer (score 3):

`INT_MIN`, as 2's complement, is a power of 2 (negated) and so has an exact FP representation.  (Potential range exception 128-bit `int` and 32-bit `float`)

Thus the math in `(n) >= (LUA_NUMBER)(LUA_MININTEGER)` is exact without conversion/rounding error.

---

Yet a functional problem exist for 64-bit floating point and 32-bit `int` in the `if()` tests.

`lua_numbertointeger(n,p)` is wrong in an edge case.  As `(LUA_INTEGER)(n)` truncates the fractional portion of `n`, I'd expect the correct preceding `if` test to be `(n) - (LUA_NUMBER)(LUA_MININTEGER) > -1  ...` instead of `(n) >= (LUA_NUMBER)(LUA_MININTEGER)`.  This allows values in `(LUA_MININTEGER - 1 ... LUA_MININTEGER)` to convert.

The value range on conversion should be

```
(INT_MIN - 1 .... INT_MAX + 1)
// not 
[INT_MIN     .... INT_MAX + 1)
```

Comment: `This allows values in (LUA_MININTEGER - 1 ... LUA_MININTEGER) to convert.` - Such float values exist only in rare non-standard Lua config "int32 + float64".  You can build such Lua yourself, but standard Lua has "int64+float64".

Comment: I think that, for 64 bit float and 32 bit int `lua_numbertointeger` wouldn't be used (at least for comparison ops in the lua VM) because it could convert the integer to a float without losing precision (and so do the comparison that way). But it's still good to know, thank you.